# How can the BIOS release date be changed for a VirtualBox VM?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, bios

I am trying to change the DMI BIOS information in my Windows 7 VM (Virtualbox). I have read the Virtualbox User Manual (Ch 9.9 p. 261). However, I don't understand the format being used to change the information nor how to change the BIOS release date in particular since there are 4 lines (2 for BIOSRelease and 2 for BIOSFirmware). Besides wanting to know how to set the BIOS date, I would like to ask you as well:

- In the lines given, is it require to write < VM-name > with angle quotatoin marks? in some other tutorials I've seen the VM name encased in double quotation marks "VM-name". I thought that that the angle quotation marks were to be omitted but I'm not sure if I have to do that here or not.
- What's the difference between BIOSRelase and BIOSFirmware? What about the number 1, 2, 3, 4 at the end of the commands? What do they mean? And how may I change the date?
- What are the DMI BIOS information types (0, 1, 2, 3 and 4)?
- Do I need to run these commands in the same directory as where the VMs are found or since the VBoxManage command is already added to path I can run the lines anywhere I want?

[DMI BIOS information (type 0) commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaKGO.png)

Comment: In manuals, something like `<Name>` is a placeholder, to be completely (including the less than/greater than characters) replaced with the actual value.

Comment: I think that values set in BIOS will affect both Guest and Host machine. Such values would be set in the Host.

Comment: Thank you @DanielB and John for your replies. What do you mean with your comment John? I don't quite understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for a Windows host (very similar to Linux):

- Open a command prompt window
- Execute `cd C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox`
- Execute

  ```
  VBoxManage setextradata "YOUR_VM_NAME" "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled" 1
  ```

  This disables syncing the time with the host.
- Get the desired date you want
- Run PowerShell
- Type :

  ```
  ([datetime]"MM/DD/YYYY" - [datetime]::Now)
  ```

  Note the displayed "TotalMiliseconds".
  Include the starting minus but stop at the dot and don't include it.
- Type `exit` to exit PowerShell
- Type :

  ```
  VBoxManage modifyvm "YOUR_VM_NAME" --biossystemtimeoffset {TotalMiliseconds value}
  ```

Comment: This will change the virtualized real-time clock. It will do nothing regarding the release date the BIOS DMI data reports.

Comment: Thank you @harrymc but Daniel B is right, it has nothing to do regarding the BIOS release date reported by DMI reports. Therrefore, does any of you know how I could change this? I've tried the 3rd command in the picture (see link in main post) but any changes I make on the date are not set in my vm (the release date is always 23-06-1999). Therefore, do you guys know what should I do?

Comment: Try `VBoxManage setextradata "My VM" "VBoxInternal/Devices/pcbios/0/Config/DmiBIOSReleaseDate" "Host BIOS Release Date"` ([link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/admin/changedmi.html)). Not sure about the date format, but it might be "DD/MM/YYYY" or that of your system.